# Ist "jemand anders" standardsprachlich korrekt?

Tags: phrase

> Im nächsten Jahr macht's dann jemand anders.

*Süddeutsche Zeitung Magazin*

Eignet sich dieser Ausdruck auch für die Standardsprache und für schriftliche Texte oder klingt es zu umgangssprachlich?

Comment: In einem formalen Umfeld finde ich es etwas zu umgangssprachlich.

Comment: Als Ersatz für "jemand anderes" (im Sinne von *ein anderer*) ist *jemand anders* schlichtweg falsch. Es kann im mündlichen Verkehr natürlich leicht vorkommen, dass man das e verschluckt, und das Wort hört sich dann an wie "anders". Schreiben muss man es aber trotzdem mit e, also "anderes".

Comment: Um alle Zweifel auszuräumen: Im Titel geht es darum, ob "jemand anders" standardsprachlich korrekt ist, d.h. um die korrekte Form des Indefinitpronomens "ander". Beim Text ist daneben eine zweite Interpretation möglich: Es könnte darum gehen, ob man den gesamten Satz auch in der Standardsprache verwenden kann, und zwar so wie er dort steht, mitsamt seiner Bedeutung. Doch was dort steht handelt nicht mehr davon, dass "jemand anderes etwas" erledigt, sondern davon dass jemand "etwas anders erledigt". Das Adverb "anders" ist korrekt ohne "e" geschrieben, aber darum ginge es ja dann nicht mehr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> a) Diese Aufgabe muss dann jemand **anders erledigen**.
>
> b) Diese Aufgabe muss dann **jemand anderes** erledigen.

Ob sich a) als Ausdruck für die Standardsprache eignet, hängt davon ab, was der Sprecher aussagen möchte. Die Sätze a) und b) sind nämlich beide "richtig", haben jedoch eine unterschiedliche Bedeutung. Warum ist das so? Weil hier zwei unterschiedliche Wörter vorliegen.

**Jemand erledigt etwas anders** 
In a) haben wir es mit dem **Adverb** [**anders**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anders) zu tun, das im Sinne von *abweichend von etwas*, *nicht so* oder *auf eine andere Weise* gebraucht wird. Satz a) bedeutet demnach, dass jemand die Aufgabe *auf eine andere Weise, aber nicht so wie zuvor* erledigen soll.

**Jemand anderes erledigt etwas** 
In b) haben wir es hingegen mit dem **Indefinitpronomen** [**ander**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ander) zu tun, das im Sinne von *nicht derselbe/ dieselbe/ dasselbe* gebraucht wird. Satz b) bedeutet demnach, dass nicht dieselbe Person, sondern eine andere Person die Aufgabe erledigen soll.

**Weiteres Beispiel** 
Vielleicht wird der Unterschied in folgendem Beispiel noch deutlicher:

> c) Wollen Sie etwas **anders machen**?
>
> d) Wollen Sie **etwas anderes** machen?

Satz c) fragt danach, ob jemand eine Sache *auf andere Weise* machen möchte. Satz d) fragt danach, ob jemand *eine ganz andere Sache* machen möchte.

Vermutlich sind sich viele Leute gar nicht darüber bewusst, dass **anders** und **ander** zwei verschiedene Wörter sind, weshalb sie in der Umgangssprache oft durcheinander gebracht werden. Standardsprachlich "richtig" wäre aber nur dasjenige Wort, was zu der entsprechenden Bedeutung passt.

Answer (score 3):

Ist im Prinzip korrekt, allerdings würde ich "jemand anderes" schreiben und nicht "jemand anders".

Alternative: "ein Anderer" - das bringt allerdings das Geschlechtsproblem mit sich, dann müsste man korrekterweise schreiben: "ein Anderer/eine Andere". Aus genau diesem Grund würde ich "jemand anderes" vorziehen.

Comment: Wieso müsste man "korrekterweise" die weibliche Form dazu schreiben? Bezieht sich "ein Anderer" ganz explizit nur auf einen Mann? Würdest du es so verstehen, als würde es sich zwingend auf einen Mann beziehen? Diese Frage soll ein Anderer beantworten.

Comment: Zur Groß- und Kleinschreibung von "ein anderer" empfehle ich das Video http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/rechtschreibung/der-andere-rechtschreibung.php.

Comment: @Philipp *muss* man nicht unbedingt, das ist umstritten. Manche haben kein Problem damit, andere schon. Politisch korrekt wäre die Nennung beider Formen. Wie auch immer man dazu steht, ich würde die "jemand"-Form bevorzugen, um das Problem einfach komplett zu umgehen.

Comment: Es gibt ja neuerdings auch den gruseligen Trend, zum Beispiel bei der Zeitschrift ze.tt, Sternchen zu benutzen: _"Ich habe seit gestern eine*n andere*n Frisör*in."_

Answer (score 2):

Je nachdem in welchem Kontext der schriftliche Text zu finden ist, gibt es diverse Varianten.

In einer eMail innerhalb der Arbeitsgruppe reicht die Form "jemand anderes", jedoch schwingt dabei auch ein wenig Respektlosigkeit mit bzw. kann von den Kollegen als solche aufgefasst werden.

Formaler wird es dann in einer eMail an einen Vorgesetzten oder eine fremde Institution (z.B. eine Behörde). Hier wäre eine andere Form empfehlenswert, z.B. "Ein Abschluss dieser Aufgabe ist mir [aus zeitlichen/erfahrungsseitigen/etc. Gründen] leider nicht möglich". Damit umgeht man die eher flapsige Tonart im Satz "Das muss dann eben jemand anderes erledigen!".

In Texten ist es besonders wichtig, nicht den täglichen Ton zu verwenden, da dieser eben keinen Ton mit sich bringt und durch fehlende Mimik und Gestik immer frei in der Interpretation durch den Lesenden ist.

Comment: Das hat überhaupt nichts mit Formalität oder dem guten Ton zu tun, sondern einzig damit, ob man das Adverb _anders_ oder das Indefinitpronomen _ander_ meint.

Comment: Die Fragestellung seitens Dreikäsehoch bezieht sich darauf, ob die Aussprache "anders" in Bezug auf Personen als schriftlicher Ausdruck (respektive "der gute Ton") ausreicht oder ob dieser als zu umgangssprachlich wahrgenommen wird. Es hat also überhaupt nichts damit zu tun, ob jemand etwas anders erledigt.

PS: Dein Kommentar ist übrigens weit ab vom guten Ton.

Comment: Mit keinem Wort wird erwähnt, dass es ihm um die Aussprache in der gesprochenen Standardsprache ginge.

Comment: Bitte die Frage korrekt lesen: Eignet sich dieser Ausdruck auch für die Standardsprache und für schriftliche Texte oder klingt es zu umgangssprachlich?

Comment: ... **und für schriftliche Texte** ... . Nebenbei ändert das rein gar nichts an meiner Kritik.

Comment: Ganz ehrlich, soll der Fragesteller entscheiden, welche Antwort hilft und welche eben nicht. Und du solltest eventuell an deiner Art und Weise der "Kritik" arbeiten, denn in deinem Text kommt genau das zum Tragen, was ich angesprochen habe.

Comment: Beim nächsten mal stelle ich die Floskel _Ich möchte den gnädigen Herren darauf Hinweisen, dass ..._ voran und formuliere die Aussage dann im höflichen Konjunktiv. Dann aber bitte auch Sie etwa so: _Ich würde Ihnen gern empfehlen, die Frage noch einmal zu lesen ..._ Meine Güte!

Comment: Man möchte das letzte Wort haben? Bitte, geschenkt.