# "Nein, es ist jemand anderes" – Declension of "andere"

Tags: grammatical-case, adjective, declension, indefinite-pronoun

> - Nein, es ist jemand anderes.
> - Das ist etwas anderes

Could someone please explain why is **anderes** and not **andere**?

Since I believe **anderes** is here a predicative adjective it should go in the base form: *andere*

Comment: The base form is [_ander_](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ander) not _andere_. The declension is described [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:anderer).

Comment: thanks, still I don't see the logic for the declension

Comment: Some links: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/dativ-von-jemand-anderes-jemandem-anderen-oder-jemand-anderem https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39225/ist-jemand-anders-standardsprachlich-korrekt/ https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37682/von-jemand-anderen-oder-von-jemand-anderem

Comment: Close voters: A declension table doesn't tell me which form of *ander-* is used with *jemand*. In fact, the Duden grammar dedicates a whole section to the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is *anderes*?

*Anderes* is a (probably substantivated) adjective (indefinite base forms: *anderer/andere/anderes*). It is an apposition to the indefinite pronouns *jemand* and *etwas*, respectively:

> - Nein, es ist [jemand [anderes]]
> - Das ist [etwas [anderes]]

---

#### Which form is *anderes* here?

This is not so unambiguous. The *Duden-Grammatik* (§ 1586) identifies it as perceived as *nominative 'or' accusative neuter*, but also states that it was a genitive form originally.

Maybe the reason for your confusion is that there are two nominative neuter singular forms of *anderes*: the 'weak' (as *das andere Haus*, *das Andere*) and the 'strong' (*ein andere**s** Haus*, *ein Andere**s***).  Since *jemand* and *etwas* are indefinite, we need to use the 'strong' form *anderes* here.

---

#### Which case of *anderes* is required?

**You expected an endingless form because you assumed it was a predicative adjective. But as we saw, it is an apposition instead.** As 'close' apposition, the case of *anderes* needs to be congruent with the syntactical function of *jemand* or *etwas*, respectively, even if they themselves remain without ending.

In your examples, the whole phrase *indefinite pronoun + apposition* is a *predicative nominative* as required by the verb *sein*. Thus, *anderes* is nominative.

In other contextes, we might need the accusative (which has the same ending) or the genitive or dative (which have separate endings):

> Ich habe jemand ander**es** gesehen. (accusative, same ending as nominative)
>
> Ich bin jemand ander**em** begegnet. (dative)
>
> Ich wohne in jemand ander**en** Haus. (genitive, somewhat unusual)

Sometimes forms of *jemand* with endings are used:

> Ich wohne in jemand**es** anderen Haus.

Same is possible with the pronouns *niemand* or *wer*:

> Das ist **niemand** anderes.
>
> Das ist **wer** anderes.

To avoid this hassle, you could use the invariable adverb *anders* with *jemand*, *niemand* and *wer* (but not with *etwas*):

> Nein, es ist jemand **anders**.
>
> Ich spreche mit jemand **anders**.

Comment: "Since jemand and etwas are indefinite, we need to use the 'strong' form anderes here."... it is a rule I should know? I mean when should I use strong vs weak forms?

Comment: How would you translate  Nein, es ist jemand anders?, anders could be "different" or "another"

Comment: @mathlover Translation definitely would be _"No, it's someone different."_

Comment: @mathlover Yes, there are two complete different ending sets for adjectives. With definite determiners (e.g., definite articles) you use the 'weak' ones: *das **schöne** Wetter, dem **schönen** Wetter* etc. With indefinite or without determiners you use the 'strong' ones: **schönes** Wetter, **schönem** Wetter etc.

Comment: @mathlover *Jemand anderes* and *jemand anders* are equivalent.

Comment: is anders also a strong form, so that we are allowed to use it here?

Comment: @mathlover *Anders* is an **adverb**, thus it has no endings at all. Like all adverbs, it's *uninflectable*.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, *ander‑* stands in **[apposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)** to the pronoun *jemand*. Some similar constructions:

> Hast du **jemand Interessanten** getroffen?
>
> Das sagt **niemand Geringeres** als die Kanzlerin selbst.
>
> Ich hab gestern **wen Nettes** kennengelernt.

Historically speaking, *ander-* is an adjective (the *‑er‑* is in fact the comparative ending). A (nominalised) adjective in apposition to a masculine pronoun such as *jemand* should show the **[strong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Strong_inflection)** masculine singular ending, e.g. *-er* in the nominative and *-em* in the dative:

> oder daß einer ein Kleinod mit einem Bildnis finde, welches vermutlich **jemand anderer** vorher verloren hat ([1](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Wieland,+Christoph+Martin/Romane/Die+Abenteuer+des+Don+Sylvio+von+Rosalva/Zweiter+Teil/F%C3%BCnftes+Buch/Erstes+Capitel))
>
> und erzählte ihr alles, mehr als sie je irgend **jemand anderem** erzählt hatte ([2](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Schnitzler,+Arthur/Romane/Therese/71))

However, there are also forms **invariably** ending in *-es*, similar to *niemand Geringeres* and *wen Nettes* above. For instance, in the accusative and dative:

> der Mensch sieht in jedem Übelbefinden und Mißgeschick etwas, wofür er irgend **jemand anderes** leiden lassen muß ([3](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Nietzsche,+Friedrich/Morgenr%C3%B6te/Erstes+Buch/15.+Die+%C3%A4ltesten+Trostmittel))
>
> wir können uns selber kitzeln und dabei genau dieselben Empfindungen haben, als wenn wir von **jemand anderes** gekitzelt würden ([4](https://archive.org/details/lehrbuchderpsych00titc/page/158/mode/2up))

I think that § 1586 of the Duden grammar (as cited by amadeusamadeus) is correct in that the forms in *‑es* are former genitives. However, examples such as (4) are incompatible with the theory that *‑es* has been reinterpreted as a neuter singular ending, as neuter dative singular would be *‑em*.

As far as the distribution of unexpected invariable *‑es* vs. the expected masculine ending *‑er, ‑en, ‑em* is concerned: In the dative, masculine *‑em* is more popular than invariable *‑es*. In the nominative, the reverse is true: invariable *‑es* is more popular than masculine *‑er*.

A minor complication for *ander‑* is that the inflected adjective *anderes* can be shortened to both *andres* and *anders*; in the latter variant, it is identical to the adverb *anders* (which is itself derived from the genitive *anderes*, with syncope of the second *‑e‑*).

Comment: How can jemand be a masculine pronoun? It is indefined

Comment: @mathlover Gender as a grammatical category is (in principle) independent of meaning. *Jemand, der etwas anderes glaubt, irrt.*

Comment: I meant indefinite. In my dictionary no gender is given to a word like jemand. I thought that because it is indefinite, it could be anything

Comment: @mathlover Well, it derives from *man(n)*, it has the masculine ending *-en* in the accusative singular (*Kennst du jemanden?*), stands with a masculine relative pronoun (*jemand, den ich sehr schätze*) and, potentially, a masculine adjective (*jemand anderer*). As a noun, it is masculine as well (*dieser Jemand war seine Frau*).

Comment: @DavidVogt "I do not understand how examples such as (4) are compatible with the theory that *‑es* has been reinterpreted as a neuter singular ending": Your example (4) is *jemand anders* which you identify as the shortened form of the adjective, 'identical' with the adverb *anders* if I understood correctly. However, Duden grammar, [duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anders) and [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anders#d-1-2) understand *anders* in connection with an indefinite pronoun as an adverb similiar or even synonymous to *sonst* in *sonst jemand*, *niemand sonst*.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I guess the simplest counterargument is that the *-es* form also occurs for words other than *ander-* that don't have adverbs on *-s*. DWB quotes Goethe:  *da ist ein Brief; er muß von **jemand Hohes** sein*.