# jemand Verantwortliches - wieso sächlich?

Tags: word-usage, gender

Hab in einem Buch gelesen "dass jemand Verantwortliches die Zeit findet..." und jetzt beim Googeln finde ich auch haufenweise Beispiele - aber wieso sächlich? Es wird doch bestimmt für eine Person verwendet! Ist das eine geschlechtsneutrale Form aus den letzten Jahren oder schon immer so verwendet?

Comment: Siehe (auf Englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59522/nein-es-ist-jemand-anderes-declension-of-andere/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das ist (erstaunlicherweise) keine neue Entwicklung, die in irgendeiner Weise mit Gendern zu tun hätte, sondern kann schon immer so formuliert werden.

Nominalisierte Adjektive (dein Beispiel ist eins) nach den Indefinitpronomen *jemand* bzw. *niemand* können entweder im Maskulinum oder im Neutrum verwendet werden.

- Jemand Verantwortliche(s/r)
- Niemand Zuständige(s/r)
- er arbeitet mit jemand Unbekanntes
- Er arbeitet mit jemand Unbekanntem

Während das Maskulinum wie im letzten Beispiel im Dativ steht, wird das Neutrum nicht sichtbar flektiert.

Siehe dazu auch https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Pronomen/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-jemand3.html?lang=de

Erstaunlicherweise führt Leo noch ein letztes Beispiel an, das das Maskulinum mit "mit" im Akkusativ verwendet. Diese Form ist als "teilweise umgangssprachlich" markiert - Ich kenne das nicht so.

Comment: mich wundert ein bisschen, dass ich es jetzt zum ersten Mal bemerkt habe - schließlich habe ich einen Haufen Bücher auf Deutsch gelesen

Comment: "er arbeitet mit jemand Unbekanntes" klingt für mich völlig falsch, genau wegen der fehlenden Flexion. Wird das tatsächlich so verwendet, außer durch Sprecher, die auch andernorts mit der Grammatik auf Kriegsfuß stehen? Ich würde vielmehr davon ausgehen, dass in "Er arbeitet mit jemand Unbekanntem" je nach Sprecher Maskulinum oder Neutrum verwendet wird; man sieht dem Satz schließlich nicht an, was gemeint war.

Comment: Wie wäre _mit jemandem Unbekanntes_? kommt mir auch ein bisschen schräg vor, aber weniger als _mit jemand Unbekanntes_.

Comment: Ich habe da meine eigenen Ansichten dazu, verweise aber einfach auf den angegebenen Link - Der wird's schn wissen....